# Is there a way to apply a function on all elements of a slice in go?

Tags: go

How do I apply a function to all elements of go slice without having to explicitly iterate over the slice?

Is there something similar to Java

`stream().map(<fn>)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

(OR)

`forEach(<fn>)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: If you don't want to write the loop, write a function that performs the loop, then call the function where you want to use a functional notation instead of a loop. If the function is not exported the compiler will probably inline it.

Comment: It is called a "for-loop".

Comment: Don't see why the hate on this question, it's a legitimate question of how to translate patterns from other languages into Go.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but in a typical Go way, not a typical Java way:

```
for _, elem := range mySlice {
    fn(elem)
}
```

Go is built on a foundation of *simplicity* - its lack of features and "sugar" is itself a feature of the language.